# How to I allow outside access to port 8080?

Tags: router, firewall, webserver

I'm trying to add a rule to my router to allow outside access of a web app running on one of my computers on port 8080.

When creating a rule, my router (actionTec) asks for three fields: "Port Start", "Port End", and "Port Map Start".

I think I understand what start and end would be, but then the port map start throws me into confusion. What should the values of these three be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enter `8080` in each field.